# Making a variable global for different requests

Tags: php

So, I have the following php variable in header:

```
<?php 
   $something = get_something();
?>
```

I have a page that is loaded via ajax and I want to use this variable without requesting it again.

How do I make this variable global so that I can use it even when a page is loaded via ajax?

Thanks

Comment: Once the page is loaded the PHP variable is gone. You could output it client side then send it to your PHP script; or you could store it in a SESSION variable.

Comment: that makes sense. I think I am going to use SESSION variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your purpose will be served by session variables actually.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = get_something();
```

> Note: You need to call the `session_start()` function before setting / getting values if you haven't done it already for the same request.